# Can't create a new github page for my repository

Tags: github

I had a repository with a github page associated to it. However, I'm on a free-tier account and wanted to use the page for a different repository. I deleted the older repository. However, I'm unable to create a github page to my new repository as it keeps prompting me to upgrade. How can i reuse my one free github page?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a delay in system changes, so if you've deleted the old repository linked to your GitHub Pages site and are having trouble setting up a new site, try waiting for a while.

After that, make sure you're seeing the most recent information from GitHub by clearing the cache and cookies in your browser. If the issue continues, you might want to ask for help from GitHub support. If you have access to another GitHub account, consider utilizing it to create the GitHub Pages website. Make sure you control the new repository and have the required rights. You should also confirm that the repository's GitHub Pages settings are set up appropriately.